# Inconsistency in Validate duplicates in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am having problems when validating the data entered in a datagridview, even if I enter a different code this validates it for me.

With this code I search for the product or data that is shown in the datagrid view

```
Private Sub dgvdetalle_KeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles dgvdetalle.KeyUp

    dt = negLog.buscar_pro_parametro(VGlobales.Base, Me.dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value)

    For Each data As DataRow In dt.Rows
        'Dim aa As Integer = Me.dgvdetalle.Rows.Add()
        ' Me.dgvproductoscanjes.Rows(aa).Cells(0).Value = data("seleccionar").ToString().Trim
        Me.dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value = data("IDPRODUCTO").ToString()
        Me.dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value = data("DESCRIPCION").ToString()

    Next

End Sub
```

And with this code in the CellEndEdit datagridview event
I do the validation.

```
Private Sub dgvdetalle_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvdetalle.CellEndEdit

    Dim clave As String
    Dim nlinea As Integer
    Select e.ColumnIndex
        Case 0
            clave = dgvdetalle.Rows(dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value
            nlinea = dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Index
            For i As Integer = 0 To dgvdetalle.Rows.Count - 1
                If clave = dgvdetalle.Rows(dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value And i <> nlinea Then
                    dgvdetalle.Rows(nlinea).Cells(0).Value = ""
                    MsgBox("esta repetido el codigo")
                    SendKeys.Send("{UP}")
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
    End Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some reason you are not using the grids `CellValidation` event for this? It is specifically made for this. In addition, “what” object is the “dgvdetalle_KeyUp” event subscribed to?… I am just saying that… if the `KeyUp` event is subscribed to the “GRID” which it appears to be… then it is NEVER fired when the user types characters into an "edited" grid cell. I suggest you put a breakpoint or debug statement to confirm this.

Comment: If you want to capture the keys pressed when the user “edits” a cell… then typically, you would wire-up whatever “KeyPress/KeyUp” event you want to the individual text box cell the user is typing into. This can be done in the grids `EditingControlShowing` event and there are many examples you can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with this line `If clave = dgvdetalle.Rows(dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value And i <> nlinea Then`

`clave` will always be equal to   `dgvdetalle.Rows(dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value` because that is what you assigned to it. The loop is not changing the current row, it is only changing the value of `i`.
You want to compare `clave` to `dgvdetalle.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString`.

The `ToString` is necessary with Option Strict On which it should be. Turn it on in Project Properties on the Compile tab and in the Tools menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults.

I changed the Select Case to an If since there was only a single case.

```
Private Sub dgvdetalle_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvdetalle.CellEndEdit
    Dim clave As String
    Dim nlinea As Integer
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        clave = dgvdetalle.Rows(dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(0).Value.ToString
        nlinea = dgvdetalle.CurrentRow.Index
        For i As Integer = 0 To dgvdetalle.Rows.Count - 1
            If clave = dgvdetalle.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString And i <> nlinea Then
                dgvdetalle.Rows(nlinea).Cells(0).Value = ""
                MsgBox("esta repetido el codigo")
                SendKeys.Send("{UP}")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```